# How can can i give git root access after changing my repo keeping history?

Tags: git, github, version-control

Am new to `git` i understand the main idea but i came across particular issue with my team and we are kind of confused so i will try to explain it.

We have a project (live) and we were pushing from the repository (ex: bitbucket) directly to the server with root access ( for files permissions and access). Then the manager decided to switch the repository to Github, now we push our local changes to github but for live we did the following:

```
git remote add [newname] ssh://[username]@[website]/var/www/[folder]/repo/site.git
```

then:

```
git push [newname] [oldname]
```

I would like to just use

```
git push [branch]
```

and it will automatically push to the server and giving Github root access so i don't need to rewrite permissions. I also would like to keep `git` history if possible, is there a way beside deleting the existing .git folder and creating a new git init in my server ?!

Comment: This isn't clear - if you are pushing directly from local to your production server (which is generally a bad idea), then what does Github have to do with anything?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth sorry for not clarifying, am pushing to github then from github to production. my issue is now my files are being sent to the server with the [username] instead of [root] being the owner and i have to change the permissions every time i push ( which will be a headache since we are a team). Before i gave Bitbucket the root permission and when ever i push from my repository to the server its automatically taking the right permissions. Hope this clarify my point!

Comment: @ALJ Based on the commands you listed, it only shows how to push local repo to github, it seems not related to bitbucket server root permission. Do you means yo move `.git` folder from `/root/username` to `/root` (the parent) directory of your bitbucket server?